# How do I recover Raid 5 data on OC Linux (mdadm)

Tags: linux

I have a raid 5 array on a linux mdadm system.

After the light went out it stopped starting. Most likely a disk flew off or some kind of malfunction. In this case I need a special utility that can rebuild my raid from the remaining working drives,
and restore them.

Digging around on the internet I saw many programs. None of them could rebuild my raid.

Only one programme "R-studio" was able to reassemble my raid, but to restore files from it did not work. All files are equal to "0" zero size.

Please advise me how to be? Or maybe some verified program?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any program: as long as only one disk in a RAID 5 has failed, your RAID is still functional. So, Linux can still use them, at least for read access, no problem.

To restore the RAID to full functionality, you'll need to replace the failed disk, and add the new disk to the RAID. So, the only program you need is `mdadm`.

Now, I don't know what you did with "I saw many programs"; it's fully possible you made matters worse and broke things further, unless you took care to never actually touch the data or metadata of your md raid.